# CSRF token missing in Django form submission

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django, django-models

I am trying to submit a form via ajax.My template is as follows:-

```
<form method="POST" id="form1" class="SignUP signupform">
        <div class="classheading">Sign-up</div>
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="text" name="user" placeholder="Username" class="sinput" required="true" />
        <input type="text"name="email" placeholder="Email" class="sinput" required="true"/>
        <input type="password"name="password"placeholder="Password" class="sinput" required="true"/>
        <input type="password"placeholder="Re-enter Password" class="sinput" required="true"/>
        <button type="submit" class="subform">Sign Up</button>
</form>
```

while ajax view submitting this form is:-

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#form1').submit(function(){
    console.log('form is submitted');

    var csrftoken = $("[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").val();

    var formdata={
        'username':$('input[name=user]').val(),
        'email':$('input[name=email]').val(),
        'password1':$('input[name=password]').val(),
        'password2':$('input[name=password1]').val(),
    };
    console.log("Formvalue is taken");

    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:'/Submit/signingup',
        data:formdata,
        dataType:'json',
        encode:true,
        headers:{
        "X-CSRFToken": csrftoken
        },
    })

    .done(function(data){
        console.log(data);
    });


    event.preventDefault();
});
 });
```

On backend, i'm submitting this form using Django.Corresponding View is as follows:-

```
@csrf_protect
def signup(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = SignupForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        user = form.save(commit=False)
        user.is_active = False
        user.save()
        current_site = get_current_site(request)
        mail_subject = 'Activate your blog account.'
        message = render_to_string('acc_active_email.html', {
            'user': user,
            'domain': current_site.domain,
            'uid':urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.pk)).decode(),
            'token':account_activation_token.make_token(user),
        })
        to_email = form.cleaned_data.get('email')
        email = EmailMessage(
                    mail_subject, message, to=[to_email]
        )
        email.send()
        return HttpResponse("Confirm your email.")
else:
     return JsonResponse({'success': False,'errors': [(k, v[0]) for k, v in form.errors.items()]})
```

But it's showing 403 error.In command prompt, it's showing "CSRF_TOKEN missing or incorrect".
What could be the possible error?

Comment: have you tried configuring the ajax csrf like [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/csrf/#setting-the-token-on-the-ajax-request)?

Answer (score 1):

put csrf_token right after from open tag like this. and try

```
<form method="POST" id="form1" class="SignUP signupform">{% csrf_token %}
```

Comment: Now it is giving me internal server error when i entered wrong information. ` The view webapp.views.signup didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.`

Comment: Just based on your code above and what you commented here, it would seem that the form you submitted was not valid, as you don't have a handler for that if statement. Nothing was returned. Handle your is.valid and try again.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$.ajax({
   url: url ,
   dataType: "json",
   type: "POST",
   data:{
    data: val ,
    csrfmiddlewaretoken: "{{ csrf_token }}",

   },
   success: function(data){
    console.log(data)
   }
 })
```